# Failed rails validations and browser back button issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form with multiple steps. After each step, the respective form is saved to the db.

The second step in the form is to create a new user. The save_user method saves this user.
Unfortunately, if somebody encounters several validation errors while attempting to fill out the user form, and they wish to return to step 1, they will have to click the browser's back button several times (depending on how many times validation failed) and in doing so possibly overwrite the saved user as they click the next/save button to go forward to the next step again.

**How can I prevent this from happening and create a better experience for the user?
I would like to not have the failed validation form instances rendered if possible so the user can go directly back to the previous step.**

```
  def save_user

     ...

    if @user.save
      redirect_to next_step_path
    else
      render 'new'

    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form submission is an HTTP POST, which means a browser is going to see it as a new pageview. I can't think of a way to do this via form submissions that doesn't result in several history entries.

Your best bet is to use JavaScript & [HTML5](http://alistapart.com/article/forward-thinking-form-validation) to validate your form before submission. At its simplest, you'll check your usernames & passwords for your length/character set restrictions, check the email address for validity, and other simple checks. If most of your users are on modern browsers and you don't mind the occasional multi-back step, then some extra attributes on your `<input>` elements will be all you need.

These checks won't help you enforce uniqueness, though. If you want to do that - to make sure usernames are unique before a user hits 'submit', say - then you'll need to use JavaScript. You'd create a new controller action that takes a username as a parameter and returns true or false depending on whether the name is free. Then you can make an AJAX request to that action and update the form to indicate whether that username was valid.